# RegExe Reqtify : capturing multilines Requirements

Tags: regex, requirements

I'm new here and I'm also a beginner in `regex`.

I'm using `Reqtify` to match and capture Requirements from a PDF file.

**Here the example of the file content:**

```
**Requirement1** 

Text of the first requirement bla bla 

Second line of the first requirement.

**Requirement2** 

Text of the second requirement, no second line

**Heading 2[Distributed]**

**Requirement3** 
Text of the third requirement

Second line of the third requirement 

Third line of the third requirement 

**Heading 1[Distributed]**

**Requirement4**
 
Text of the 4th requirement

Second line of the 4th requirement 

Third line of the 4th requirement 

**Heading3[Distributed]**
[...]
```

**Here what i want for the Requirement3 for example :**

```
Text of the third requirement
Second line of the third requirement 
Third line of the third requirement
```

As can you see the file mixes requirements and different heading (1,2,3 etc).

My first idea was to capture each requirement until the line which ends with ***"]"**.

So my regex pattern is:

```
(^Requirement\d+).*$\n(\s\S]*?)^.*Distributed\]$
```

But it doesn't work well (see picture below).

[image]

My second idea is to have different **end of the multiline**, something like this:

```
(^Requirement\d+).*$\n(\s\S]*?)**^.*Distributed\]$|^Heading\d+**
```

But it doesn't work at all, i know that the regex syntax isn't right.

**Can someone, please, help with the two ideas?**

Thank you for your time.

Also, if you have documentation about regex in Reqtify I would love to read it.

PS: I use regex101 to test my expression.

---

Thank to @GreyMurav I can capture what I want. However I noticed that in the file, in each page there  are a header and a footer, so in some requirement they are captured.

The header its like this :

'#TABLE

'#TR|1 bla bla bla bla

'#TR[1...................... Distributed|5 page 5/102

SO you can have something like this :
Requirements 5

First line of the requirement

*#TABLE

#TR|1 bla bla bla bla

#TR[1...................... Distributed|5 page 5/102*

The rest of the requirement bla bla.

Here what I tried :

1. add a non-capturing group '''
   (?:^#TABLE\nTR.*\n#TR.*Distributed.*$)
   ''' I tried to place it everywhere but It doesnt work.
2. In Reqtify you can apply a sub-exopression to a group. But it doesn't work eather.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern that captures all lines after matching Requirement stops matching until a line start with `Requirement` or contains `[Distributed]`

```
^Requirement\d+\s*\n((?:(?!^Requirement\d|.*?\[Distributed]).*(?:\n|$))*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `Requirement\d+\s*\n`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!^Requirement\d|.*?\[Distributed])` Assert that the string does not start with Requirement and a digit and does not contain [Distributed]
    - `.*` Match the whole line
    - `(?:\n|$)` Match a newline or assert the end of the string
  - `)*` Close the non capture group an optionally repeat to match all lines
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DK2Dgg/1)