# Reqtify regex issue

Tags: regex, requirements

I've an issue with reqtify in order to remove a part of text.

See below an extract of the intermediate file generated by Reqtify:

`heading 1   5. Bug fixing requirements
heading 2   5.1 Detection
bullet:style1   1. The representative shall identify them
bullet:style1   2. Based on the following principles:
bullet:style2   1. Principle 1
bullet:style2   2. Principle 2
bullet:style2   3. Principle 3
NOTE    NOTE  This can block delivery
bullet:style1   3. The supplier shall kept in database
bullet:style1   â€¢ Clause 1
bullet:style1   â€¢ Clause 2
heading 2   5.2 Bug fixing meeting`

I used the following regex in reqtify:
`^bullet:style1\s*(\d.)+\s(.*)((?:(?!^bullet:style1\s*\d.|^heading).*(?:\n|$))*)`

I correctly capture the three requirements but the text contains for the 2nd and 3rd requirements, the term "bullet:style1" or "bullet:style2" or the term "NOTE" ...

I've tried to remove it by using a sub-expression without success
`^(?:bullet:style\d\s*|NOTE\s*)*(.*)`

Could you please tell me, what's wrong in my sub-expression ?

By advance, thanks for your help.

NB: The result, I'm looking for:

1st requirement: "1. The representative shall identify them"
2nd requirement: "2. Based on the following principles:

1. Principle 1
2. Principle 2
3. Principle 3
   NOTE  This can block delivery"

3rd requirement: "4. The supplier shall kept in database
â€¢ Clause 1
â€¢ Clause 2"

NB: I've used the following post to build the 1st regular expressions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724961/regexe-reqtify-capturing-multilines-requirements

NB#2: See attached the captures of my reqtify project and the associated results

Reqtify type definition and field attribute - From 1 to 4

Reqtify output without the substring application - Picture #5

Reqtify output with substring application on Field#3 - Picture #6

[image: Reqtify type definition]
[image: Reqtify type definition - Field#1 ID]
[[image: Reqtify type definition - Field#2 Text3]
[[image: Reqtify type definition - Field#3 Text4]
[image: Reqtify Output 1 without substring]
[image: Reqtify Output 2 with substring applied to Field #3]

Comment: You are repeating the match inside a capture group, see https://regex101.com/r/5VdQRR/1 You can remove the bullet parts with `^(?:bullet:style\d+|NOTE)\s*` and then replace with an empty string.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for your reply and your time.
I'm not sure to understand correctly your answer.
I've updated my reqtify type by typing the regex provided in the regex101.com website and put also the 2nd one as a substring ... Unfortunately, it seems this is not working but I'm quite sure I haven't understood your message correctly.
I've added some snapshot in my original post.